How do I setup ESlint + Prettier with Airbnb style guide for a React Native / JavaScript Project (Expo) using VS Code?
So I scouted almost every tutorial regarding this but I could not make it work.
In the tutorials when you npm install eslint it asks you in the command line if you wanna use a popular style guide, but this is not the case anymore. They all seem outdated and I did not find guides regarding the newest version for eslint.
I am not a pro regarding packages, npm, npx or react development. But I wanna learn and understand. I would appreciat it, if you could explain the commands and steps to use Airbnbs style guide in my own react native project.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Install the eslint-config-airbnb package as a devdependency with this command:
npm i -D eslint-config-airbnb

Then, add airbnb to your eslintrc file's extends property:
"extends": "airbnb"

If you install the ESLint VS Code extension, then it'll automatically highlight any issues.
Also, the command you mentioned to access the esltintrc autoconfig is actually npx eslint --init, so you can use that as well.
